# Microsoft MPI and mpi4py 3.0.0, python 3.7.1 is it currently possible at all?

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am very frustrated after a whole week of trying everything imaginable and unimaginable, it seems that their SDK ( https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57467 ) is missing something:

```
C:\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763
.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64" msmpi.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_MPI build\temp.win-amd64-3.
7\Release\src/MPI.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mpi4py\MPI.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\MPI.cp37-win_amd64.lib
    MPI.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_MPI' specified multiple times; using first specification
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\MPI.cp37-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\MPI.cp37-win_amd64.exp
    MPI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_Ireduce_scatter
    MPI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_Iallgatherv
    MPI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_Iexscan
    MPI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_Iscan
    MPI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_Ialltoallw
    MPI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_Ireduce_scatter_block
    MPI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_Ialltoall
    MPI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_Ialltoallv
    MPI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MPI_Reduce_scatter_block
    build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mpi4py\MPI.cp37-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

If it's really impossible to make it work, then tell me which distribution of MPI should I use instead of Microfost MPI, since https://www.mpich.org/downloads/ does not provide any alternatives for Windows.

P.S.: mpi4py 2.0.0 is incompatible with python 3.7 (at least Anaconda tells me so), so I 'll rather choose another distribution of MPICH (if there is one) than downgrade my python.

Answer (score 2):

I've got it working with 3.7.0...

I downloaded MSMPI from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57467
I ran both files, then added it to the PATH 
(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI)

I then just used `python -m pip install mpi4py`

To run a MPI program, I then us `mpiexec -n [number of cores] python .\filename`

I'm running on a AMD A-10 9600P in Windows 10.

I do have Visual Studio installed, so it's possible that it's hooking into some libs you don't have...

Comment: And so did I. I have all the paths, you can see it in the log. The only possible explanation (beside MS developers bug) maybe that I have too much libraries linked and they conflict somehow.
It clearly should NOT be dependent on commercial Visual Studio IDE, but only on compiler and SDK which I have installed.

Comment: I run into the similar issue. Tried downloading the mpi4py source and build from there. In the build process, I can see that it found the correct msmpi path, but the installation still gave me the same DLL not found error.

Comment: This worked for me as well. It turned out I'd MPI 7.x even with latest WIndows update and above link installed 10.x. My previous mpi2py installation was giving me "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found." so I'd uninstalled it first then followed steps here.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work finally:

1. Make sure that you download and install both msmpisdk.msi and msmpisetup.exe from the Microsoft MPI for v10.
2. Add both C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI and C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin to system PATH.
3. (Optional) Restart the cmd window and reinstall mpi4py