# OpenAI Spinning Up Problem: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, openai-gym

Going through OpenAi's "Spinning Up" tutorials series (https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/user/installation.html). When I try to bash their step "

```
python -m spinup.run ppo --hid "[32,32]" --env LunarLander-v2 --exp_name installtest --gamma 0.999
```

I get the following error:

> from mpi4py import MPI
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

From how I'm reading this the program doesn't seem to think I have the MPI module installed for mpi4py, yet when I explicitly write this code (from mpi4py import MPI) in my PyCharm IDE it recognizes the module and library no problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Error message before it:



File "C:\Users\Colin Warn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\Colin Warn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "D:\git\openaideeprl\spinningup\spinup\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from spinup.algos.ddpg.ddpg import ddpg
  File

Comment: "D:\git\openaideeprl\spinningup\spinup\algos\ddpg\ddpg.py", line 7, in <module>
    from spinup.utils.logx import EpochLogger
  File "D:\git\openaideeprl\spinningup\spinup\utils\logx.py", line 14, in <module>
    from spinup.utils.mpi_tools import proc_id, mpi_statistics_scalar
  File "D:\git\openaideeprl\spinningup\spinup\utils\mpi_tools.py", line 1, in <module>

Comment: pip install mpi4py ? perhaps sudo?check the docs https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html

Answer (score 3):

I got same error when running rl-baseline-zoon. The trick was to  first,

```
pip uninstall mpi4py
```

Then,

Install [Microsoft MPI 10.x](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57467) (both files).

And finally,

```
pip install mpi4py
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659275/207661